# Solution of this differential equation in certain area

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differiantial equation $y' = y^2\cdot x$
I've found that $y = \frac{-1}{\frac{x^2}{2}+c}$. Now I don't understand how to find all solutions in $U_1 := \{(x, y)| x > 0, y > 0\}$,
$U_2 := \{(x,y)|x < 0, y<0\}$,
$U_3 := \{(x,y)|x > 0, y<0\}$,
$U_4 := \{(x,y)|x < 0, y>0\}$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values of the constant $c$ in the denominator. If $c>0$, $y$ will always be negative, then the solutions will lie in the sets $U_2$ if $x<0$ and $U_4$ if $x>0$. In the case of $c<0$, there several cases you have to check depending on the solutions of inequalities: $x^2+2c<0$ and $x^2+2c>0$.